# Dashjs drag progress bar to 0:00:00 freeze the video

Tags: video.js, dash.js

I'm using `dashjs` and `videojs`, when I drag the progress bar to initial time (0:00:00) the video freezes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Any chance you can give us something more to work from? The dash.js reference player seems to work fine when you drag to the start or click the start of the scrubber: http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.4.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/